# IIS error - HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently installed IIS on my Windows 7 PC and when i opened `http://localhost/` it showed

```
********************ERROR**********************  
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.  
********************ERROR**********************

********************Detailed Error Information**************  
Module:  ConfigurationValidationModule  
Notification:  BeginRequest  
Handler:  StaticFile  
Error Code:  0x80070032  
Requested URL  :http://localhost:80/  
Physical Path  :C:\inetpub\wwwroot  
Logon Method  :Not yet determined  
Logon User  :Not yet determined  
************************
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory, check your configuration settings, what app have you deployed on localhost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what code/configurations you're running, but you may have to change the App Pool for your site to use *Classic* instead of *Integrated* mode.

- Here's a good [explanation of the difference](https://help.maximumasp.com/KB/a657/explanation-of-classic-vs-integrated-mode-in-iis-7x.aspx).

> Classic mode is where IIS only works with ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters directly ... Integrated mode handles all requests through a unified pipeline for IIS and is tightly integrated with ASP.NET through that same pipeline.

- And where you could be running into trouble:

> Some legacy code may require that you run in classic mode to execute without error. To take full advantage of IIS we strongly encourage you to review your code if your application throws an error in Integrated but runs fine in Classic.

- [Laundry list of issues](https://help.maximumasp.com/KB/a666/troubleshooting-integrated-pipeline-issues.aspx?KBSearchID=1752) to debug Integrated mode.

Comment: I didnt try to run any application.
I just tried to run the IIS default page.
This error comes when i try to go into that page.
THE DEFAULT ONE

Comment: @AshwinA Even the default page has a lot of configuration, including all the host configuration under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: I got it :) . Thanx for all ur help :)